# what is the mimum RAM size required to run android?

Tags: android

Link:  https://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html#android-403

According to CDD document, it is stated below

```
"Device implementations MUST have at least 340MB of memory available to the kernel 
 and userspace. 
 The 340MB MUST be in  addition to any memory dedicated to hardware components 
 such as radio, video, and so on that is not under the kernel's control."
```

**MY Understanding is:**

340 MB is required for both user and kernel space.
  340 MB is for hardware components ,

So, in total minimum 680 MB

NOTE:  Please correct me if my understanding is wrong ?

But, if i look at mobiles that are available in the market, they are not compliance with the requirement.

For example:

HTC ONE V , has 512 MB of RAM, but still runs android 4.0.3 , in which the requirement is 680MB.

Considering above, 
how the OEM vendor passes compatibility test?

Comment: this dosen't seem to be a question related to programming, for this kind of questions refer to [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or similar sites

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you need 340MB for everything in total, plus however much you need for hardware components.

Comment: 3D graphics may take more than that.  PC graphics cards generally have Gigabytes.  NVidia makes tegra chips for Android with up to 2GB of memory

Comment: Sure but that's graphics memory and not system RAM, right?

Comment: Yes, its separate than the 340 above.  But physically, RAM is RAM-  its the same chips.  So when they talk about more memory needed for hardware like radios, the graphics memory would fall in that category (which you said shouldn't be more than 100MB, that's the part I took issue with).

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the correction, I'll change the text!

Answer (score 0):

According to an interview with Andy Rubin in 2008 this is the minimum requirements for android:

32 MB RAM

32 MB Flash Memory

200 MHz processor

[Source](http://www.mycomputeraid.com/computers/google-android-system-requirements/)

---

For gingerbread, I could not find anything official, but I found a few sites that say the following:

1GHz processor

512MB Ram

3.5 inches or more screen size

[source](http://techie-buzz.com/mobile-news/android-30-gingerbread-minimum-system-requirements.html)

---

I also found an "official looking" site that has requirements, but this looks to be a couple years old and doesn't say what version of android this is spec'd for.

128 MB RAM

256 MB Flash External

QVGA TFT LCD or larger, 16-bit color or better

[Source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/system_requirements.html)